# TDD and DI for VC++ platform

Tags: c++, tdd

I am trying to setup Agile and TDD environment for MFC applications that require high performance.

Since MFC View/Document are not testable, I am going to make them as dumb as possible and to test the other classes with Boost Test framework. - Please let me know if you know better way or better test framework for this environment.

In order to make TDD work, I think having dependency injection is crucial for loosely coupled structure. How can I achieve this? Any reference or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Use shared_ptr's to interfaces representing your classes. I am thinking something like http://ideone.com/r1Ou7. Then you could just take the clock implementation in your constructor, or have another method to set the implementation, like setClock or something.

Comment: @EthanSteinberg Unfortunately, it's not that simple according to [this article](http://programmaticallyspeaking.blogspot.com/2010/04/beautiful-dependency-injection-in-c.html)

Comment: That article seems to ignore shared_ptr. The main reason why the article dislikes the use of dynamic memory(my suggestion) is because it is difficult to manage. Shared_ptr removes almost all of the management problems. However, if you cannot use shared_ptr because of performance reasons(unlikely, but possible), then things are going to get very complicated(as the article talks about).

Comment: @EthanSteinberg Hmm, I understand what you are saying. Since the characteristics of shared_ptr, lifetime of the injected object does not depend on the main object. Interesting. I will investigate it more. If you have a chance, why don't you post as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use shared_ptr's to interfaces representing your classes.

I am thinking something like

```
#ifndef CLOCK_HPP_INCLUDED
#define CLOCK_HPP_INCLUDED

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>


class Clock
{
public:
   static boost::shared_ptr<Clock> create();
   virtual void init() = 0;
   virtual double getSeconds() = 0;
   virtual void sleepUntilNext(double howMuch) = 0;

protected:  // No polymorphic deconstruction because of shared_ptr
   ~Clock()
   {}


};

#endif
```

Then you could just take the clock implementation in your constructor, or have another method to set the implementation, like setClock or something.

Example of this would be

```
#include "clock.hpp"
class MyClass
{
public: 
   myClass(boost::shared_ptr<Clock> aClock) : myClock(aClock)
   {
       myClock.init();
   }

private:
   boost::shared_ptr<Clock> myClock;
}
```

Then in your unit testing you could do something like this:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Clock> mock = createMockClock();
MyClass b(mock);

mock.assertThatInitIsCalled();
```

You can also just ignore resources. The shared_ptr's will delete themselves.

The cost to this would be a little performance loss due to dynamic allocation, virtual function calls, and the overhead of shared_ptr.

The benefits would be increased modularity, lowered compile time, easier use of mocking frameworks like googlemock(they require interfaces anyways), and easier resource management(you will never have a null pointer).

Comment: I might have liked it more if you've added some examples to show how it is injected and how lifetime of that object does not depend on the host object and so on. But I get its gist and have enough understanding to accept this question.